# How to delete an object inside of an object in mongoDB? Python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I'm trying to delete an object inside of an object in MongoDB, currently, my data structure looks like this.

Data structure of Mongo:

```
id: 145796357695733760
Name: "@x414141"
Money: 252702.84199999995
stocks: Object
     |__ MSFT: Object
     |       |_ amount: 0
     |__ AAPL: Object
     |       |_ amount: 0
     |__AMZN: Object
             |_ amount: 0
```

My current code is:

```
    for dataBaseObject in mongoReturn['stocks'].items():

        if dataBaseObject[1]['amount'] == 0:
            print(dataBaseObject)
            print(dataBaseObject[0])
            print(type(dataBaseObject))
            collection.update_one({"_id": user.id},
                                  {
                                      "$pull":
                                          {
                                              "stocks":
                                                  {
                                                      "MSFT"
                                                  }
                                          }
                                  })
```

however, it refuses to let me pull the value "MSFT" from my "stocks" object.
Can someone possibly tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good try. `$pull` is used to remove an object from an array.

> The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

You can use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

```
db.test.update({},{"$unset":{"stocks.MSFT":""}})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you don't know how long I've spent trying to fix this using every command other than unset... literally hours you've been a huge help!